# I can only make MVC 6 Sessions work when using the browser address bar

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

**Setup:**

So I have two visual studio instances running.

1) Backend: MVC 6 Application with a MVC controller called homeController

2) Frontend: Website project. HTML.

I didn't build it with the traditional Views in mvc, but a standalone HTML webpage, using the MVC backend for data. - I like having them separate.

**Test:**

So I wanted to use sessions for the first time in MVC 6 and followed [this guide](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0).

First tests went fine, as I didn't bother to write the html and ajax, I just called the mvc from the address bar like this:

http://localhost:55043/home/setsession

The code behind it is:

```
[HttpGet]
public string SetSession()
{
   string sessionId = "1";
   HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionId, "myvalue");
   return sessionId;
}
```

And then:

http://localhost:55043/home/getsession?sessionId=1

The code behind it is:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetSession(string sessionId)
{
   string value = HttpContext.Session.GetString(sessionId);
   return "session value is: " + value;
}
```

It gave my value back correctly.

**Problem:**

But when I wrote the website and its calles the same methods, then its not remembering the value set in the second call.

My code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + "/home/SetSession",
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("finito - Sessionid: " + data);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/home/GetSession",
            data: {
                sessionId: data,
            },
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (x, t, m) {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
        alert("failed);
    }
});
```

**So why is it not working for my website? What is the difference?**

Some of my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.CookieName = ".BrunataBooking";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("*")
               .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Start}/{id?}");
    });
}
```